inline-block child element has text overflow
Why do child elements in initial-block overflow? Is there any way to fix it?


.experience1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.exper {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}

.exper-date {
  background-color: aqua;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 160px;
}

.exper-review {
  background-color: beige;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 700px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.exper h4 {
  margin: 0px;
}

.exper p {
  margin: 0;
}
<div class="section" id="experience">
  <h2 class="section-title">Work experience</h2>
  <div class="experience1">
    <div class="exper exper-date">May 2022 - Present</div>
    <div class="exper exper-review">
      <h4>Y Company</h4>
      <p>
        - Build and develop Website based on existing design and requirements.
      </p>
      <p>
        - Analyze and design Database, use management systems Database (MySQL, SQLServer, NoSQL, ...) and write queries.
      </p>
      <p>
        - Use server-side languages (Python, Java, ...) to build Web Servers
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




What is initial-block?

@AHaworth There's a chance they are referring to the initial containing block, but most likely they probably meant inline-block.

@TylerH yes, I see now inline-block is in the title.

Is it okay, Văn Lộc Trần?
